# Phonegap application for webOS, alerts don't working

Tags: javascript, cordova, alert, webos

In Phonegaps application for webOS I try to show alert in several ways:

```
// 1.
alert('Mobile number has to be of 10 digits');

// 2.
navigator.notification.alert("alert text!",
    function(){}, //callback
    'alert Title',
    "ok"
);

// 3.
navigator.notification.confirm("alert text!",
    function(){}, //callback
    'alert Title',
    "ok"
);

// 4.               
Notification.prototype.confirm('alert text', function(){}, 'alert Title', 'ok');
```

Phonegaps version 2.1.0

Why it don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look at this page?

http://www.digitaldogbyte.com/2011/05/11/notifications-dashboard-in-phonegap-0-9-5-webos/

If you're following that and it's not working then it might be a regression in PhoneGap.  Alert will not work on webOS apps as they are supposed to use dashboard notifications.